# Bash script failing with -l -i parameters in shebang

Tags: bash

I'm working on some bash files and I came upon the following:

```
#!/bin/bash -l -i
```

Whats does `-l -i` mean? The script fails it has those parameters but if I remove them the script works.

Comment: Did you check `man bash`

Comment: Read [6.2 Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files) to see what happens when you launch an interactive login shell.

Comment: Also, depending on your system, the shebang line only provides *one argument* (see your [execve(2)](https://manpage.me/?q=execve) man page, so you might be starting bash like `bash "-l -i" /path/to/script` -- see if your script works with `#!/bin/bash -li` (with options compressed into one word)

Comment: Compare `PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+' bash -xli yourscript` and `PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+'  bash -x yourscript`. (The `-x` enables trace-level logging). I mean that literally -- dump stderr to a file for each of those two commands, and diff the files. You'll see the extra code that gets run with those parameters present, and will also have a trace of your script's execution so you can see exactly *why* that execution fails when the initialization code added by `-l` or `-i` is present.

Comment: ...the real problem with using anything (like these parameters) that makes your script dependent on a user's `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` is that it... well... makes your script dependent on per-user configuration -- so it's no longer guaranteed to work when run by *just anyone*, but only by a user whose dotfiles are set up the same way as the author's. But the details of where that dependency is would require an analysis of the script, and of the dotfiles; information necessary to answer it simply isn't given in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many OS including Linux only accept a single additional parameter in the shebang. Since these are both single flags without singles, you can combine them to work around it:

```
#!/bin/bash -li
```

Comment: True, but also possible that the user's dotfiles do configuration that breaks the script. Of course, we can't tell conclusively without seeing the dotfiles, and the script.